# How to determine a LFH heap from a dump

Tags: heap-memory, windbg

How is it possible in Windbg to determine if a heap has enabled LFH (low-fragmentation heap) ?
Is there any differences on XP SP3 and Vista/W7/W8

EDIT:
 Just discovered that last column in !heap –s  shows this for all heaps.

W7:

```
        Heap     Flags   Reserv  Commit  Virt   Free  List   UCR  Virt  Lock  Fast 
                          (k)     (k)    (k)     (k) length      blocks cont. heap 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000000000310000 00000002    1024    468   1024    112    29     1    0      0   LFH
```

XP SP3:

```
  Heap     Flags   Reserv  Commit  Virt   Free  List   UCR  Virt  Lock  Fast 
                    (k)     (k)    (k)     (k) length      blocks cont. heap 
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 00150000 00000002    4096   3496   3536    288    24     3    0      1   L
```

Comment: LFH was introduced in Win2000 but may not be enabled prior to Vista: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929136. `!heap -s` and `!heap -p` will display LFH info, the latter requires gflag setting 'enable page heap' but I don't know if there is a quicker mechanism that `!heap -s` given that this is the summary flag I would expect this to be the quicker way without knowing the heap address in advance to display info on, sorry I can't provide an answer

Comment: @EdChum,Thanks, I was starring on a !heap –s from  XP dump and did not understand the Fast heap column eq L. When I looked at a W7 (64) dump it became clear.